# CAT6a Shielded Home Network Installation and Shielding

Tags: ethernet, networking

I am about to run the cables for my new home network. I've chosen to use [CATa Shielded Cable](https://www.truecable.com/products/cat6a-riser-ethernet-cable-shielded?variant=13894028066883) with a rack mount setup as follows. The questions I have regard the shielding. Thank you in advance.

The cable is shielded, the keystones are shielded, and the patch panel is shielded.

- The switch and power supply have the third prong for ground on their
  power plugs. The patch panel and switch both have grounding screws on
  them. Do I just tie these screws to the rack itself and call it a day
  or is there more to it?
- Should I use [shielded patch cables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BIPSHQK) between the switch and patch
  panel?
- Finally, should I use shielded cables at the end points, i.e.
  plugging a computer into the shielded jack or any other device
  plugging into the shielded jacks?

### **Rack** - [Monoprice 4U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008CR07OM)

[image]

### Power Supply - **[CyberPower CPS1215RMS Rackmount Surge Protector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00077INZU)**

### Patch Panel - **[TRENDnet 24-Port Cat6A Shielded 1U Patch Panel, TC-P24C6AS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D5RQGKF)**

### Switch - **[TP-Link TL-SG2428P](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/omada-sdn-switch/tl-sg2428p/)**

### Jacks - [Shielded CAT6a Jacks](https://www.truecable.com/products/cat6a-toolless-keystone-jack-shielded) and housed in plastic [Keystone Jack Wall Plates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074HHDJWT)

---

**Back of patch panel with grounding wire and switch with grounding screw**
[image: Back of patch panel with grounding wire and switch with grounding screw]

Answer (score 0):

Shielding and grounding do both interplay a role in minimizing interference. The PDU should ground the rack via its metal to metal interface, so yes attaching the ground wires from the switch and patch panel to the rack should do the trick. You can actually buy a grounding bar for this purpose. Something like this https://www.startech.com/en-ca/server-management/server-rack-accessories/grounding-equipment but I don’t condone that brand.

If you’re uncertain about how the rack is grounded through the metal chassis of the PDU, you can easily attach a ground wire to the rack using a machine screw and then attach the other end of the wire to a known ground point, like the yoke screw of the outlet that powers the PDU.

Nice set up btw.

Comment: 1. Regarding the metal-to-metal interface would it help to put star washers between the rack and component holes when I screw them in to break some of the paint?
2. Do I really need a grounding bar on the rack or can I just tie the rack to ground via one of the mounting screws?
3. Tying the ground to the outlet yoke. Would I just do that with a ring terminal through the outlet screw going into the box? Will I still be able to get the face plate on after this is done or should I modify the plate or is there a special plate I can buy?